# Add message-subject to AS2 encoded message using Azure logic app

Tags: azure, http-headers, azure-logic-apps

I've created an Azure logic app that encodes some xml in an AS2 message, then sends this message to another server.

Flow:

1. Trigger[HTTP] ->
2. AS2 Encode body of trigger ->
3. Add AS2 headers and encoded body to an HTTP POST message.

It works with the default options but now I have been asked to add the AS2 header "message-subject", which is not currently available via the Logic App builder.

**How do I add the AS2 header "message-subject" to my HTTP message, using Azure logic apps?**